# How do you deep copy a multidimensional NSMutableArray and its contents?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, deep-copy

I currently have a three dimensional NSMutableArray which I need to deep copy. However, it appears that the following code causes it and its contents to become immutable, since it causes NSInvalidArgumentException when I attempt to remove any objects from it.

```
NSMutableArray* copy = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:input copyItems:YES] autorelease];
```

How can I deep copy an array without causing it to become immutable?

Comment: try  NSMutableArray* copy = [input mutablecopy];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the listing,

> The copy imlementation of immutable classes usually returns the same
> object - because it's immutable there is no need to have a "real"
> copy. But you don't have to worry about this.

above from http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/May/msg00172.html

So make sure before you add your `input` array, convert that input array into a mutable copy and then call the method.

#### Code:

```
NSMutableArray* mutableInput = [input mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray* copy = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableInput copyItems:YES]autorelease];
```

Comment: Would it work if I converted the array into a mutable array after using my previous code? Also what do you mean by "adding" the array?

Comment: @Charles, Hey I just updated my answer, try that and make sure you read the given link which describes why we need to do this. I guess this should work.

Comment: That seems to make the Array itself mutable, but for some reason the mutable arrays within the array have become immutable, so I can do [input removeObjectAtIndex]; but not [[input objectAtIndex:0] remove objectAtIndex];. Could i just use a loop to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSCoding

in .h file
@interface classname : NSObject

in .m file

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
  {
  }