# how to deep copy multidimensional NSMutableArray correctly?

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray, deep-copy

Hi this question got asked before: [How do you deep copy a multidimensional NSMutableArray and its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968021/how-do-you-deep-copy-a-multidimensional-nsmutablearray-and-its-contents)
but the answer didn't work for me.

I tried:

```
NSMutableArray *copy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:multiDimArray copyItems:YES];
```

and:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [multiDimArray mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *copy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray copyItems:YES];
```

The copying works but when I try to replace an object I get the error:

-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1073b1790

Am I doing anything wrong or is it just not possible to deep copy a multidimensional array without its elements becoming immutable?

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
NSMutableArray *originalArray = [NSMutableArray new];

NSMutableArray *copyArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSArray *subarray in originalArray) {
    NSMutableArray *subCopy = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (id item in subarray){
        [subCopy addObject:[item copy]];
    }
    [copyArray addObject: subCopy];
}
```

I did it for a two dimensional array. If there are more dimensions you probably have to add an extra for loop for every dimension.

Comment: You can probably replace that with a recursive method if it's an unlimited dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [multiDimArray mutableCopy];
```

replace with

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:multiDimArray] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: with this I get the same error message. Somehow only the first dimension of the array is mutable but all the others are immutable.